# Is there a way to change QTreeView Header color in pyqt5?

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, pyqt5

I want to be able to change the column header but anything that I try it doesn't work. Below is example of what I want to change. I want to change the white of the header.

[Example]

[image: 1]

Below is the style sheet that I have currently

```py
self.treeView.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(0, 153, 255);\n"
                                    #"color: rgb(0, 153, 255);\n"
                                    "alternate-background-color: rgb(0, 153, 255);\n"
                                    "border-style: solid;\n"
                                    "border-color: rgb(0, 153, 255);\n"
                                    "border-width: 2px;\n"
                                    "border-radius: 10px;")
```

Let me know if you need more code!

Comment: Be aware that using generic stylesheet properties is usually discouraged, especially for complex widgets like scroll areas (all item views are scroll areas). As you can see, that stylesheet completely resets the appearance of the scroll bar to the basic one (using the QCommonStyle fallback). You should *always* use *specific* [selectors](//doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet-syntax.html#selector-types), in your case: `setStyleSheet("QTreeView { ... }")` or `setStyleSheet("QTreeView::section { ... }")` as shown in the current answer. Note that `QWidget {...}` or `* {...}` behaves as using no selectors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a small complete application that shows how to set a header style for a QTreeView:

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets

class Widget(QtWidgets.QTreeView):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.test_model = QtWidgets.QFileSystemModel(self)
        self.setModel(self.test_model)

app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
app.setStyleSheet("QHeaderView::section { background-color: red }")
w = Widget()
w.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

For further information on styling the header see [the docs](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet-examples.html#customizing-qheaderview).